# Flutter Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter

Am trying to get data from an API but I keep getting the error above .
Here is how my API response is structured

```
{"cards":{"TOTAL_PERFORMED":0,"TOTAL_TO_BE_PERFORMED":0,"START_DATE":1619042400,"END_DATE":1619042400}}
```

And here is how am trying to get the data

```
Future<Map<List,dynamic>>cards_daily_request()async{
    var apiUrl = "https:/s/Dashboard/cards/daily/$rvcid";
    

    var response= await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(apiUrl),headers: {"Authorization":"$token"});
    
     List data;
    var extractdata=await json.decode(response.body);
    data=await extractdata["cards"];
    print(data[0]);
    

  
  }
```

Any idea what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is a map and not a List
In json lists are defined with square brackets [ ]

Check Json structure #3 : Simple Nested structures
In this article

https://link.medium.com/XVauCvELEfb

In short
You need an object for the json and object for the card with some factory to map it from json

Comment: Thank you. The link helped me solve the problem